# PHP web file manager

Tags: php, ftp

Im currently having some troubles to load some images from my web file manager into a php page. I have something like this in my page:

```
<?php
define("FTP_CONNECT_IP", ip);
define("FTP_CONNECT_PORT", port);

// Set username and password
define("FTP_LOGIN_USER", username);
define("FTP_LOGIN_PASS", pw);


// Connect to FTP server
$conn = ftp_connect(FTP_CONNECT_IP, FTP_CONNECT_PORT); 

// Log into FTP srever
$login_result = ftp_login($conn, FTP_LOGIN_USER, FTP_LOGIN_PASS);


if(ftp_pasv( $conn, true )){

    echo 'works';        
}else{
{
    echo 'dont works';
}
}
ftp_close($conn);

?>
```

The problem is, i have no clue about how to directly access the files from my nas (web file manager). I can get a list of all the files in the directory i specify, but i have no idea how to actually load them, and if a direct file access is alowed to be done. Any help would be appreciated, since i lack knowledge about this kind of things.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the files?

Are you trying to print the images on the page?

Comment: yes. as soon as i realise how can i get the files path, i would like to load them on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(ftp_pasv( $conn, true )){
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn, '/');`

Try adding the line above in place of your `echo 'works';` line, then check what `var_dump($contents);` shows.

To print an image in PHP, let's say you have the file path stored as a variable.  I define variables like this:

`$imageUrl = '/home/user/domain/assets/img/123.png';`

Although you can do it the way you've done above:

`define("/home/user/domain/assets/img/123.png", imgUrl);`

When you've got the URL defined, you then have to use HTML to print the image.

An example of this would be either of the following:

`echo "<img src=\"".$imageUrl."\"/>";`

The above is effectively the same as `echo "<img src=$imageUrl />";`, but properly written for validation and escaped the quotes.

or perhaps more simply, closing your php tag and opening it back up for the URL.

`?> <img src="<? echo $imageUrl; ?>" /> <?`

Both of these use HTML, the markup language to display things on webpages.

Edit: Although it is not recommended, and not safe, a viable solution to the actual problem here is to include the FTP path in the IMG tag as follows.

`<img src="ftp://user:password@domain.com:port" />`

Please also make a separate user for this purpose with only read access to that folder.

Comment: the part you are explaining i already know. what i don't know is the complete url path (like /home/user/domain/assets/). I access web file manager through browser, something like this: (http://ip:port/cgi-bin/filemanager/) and there i can find every file i need, but with the GUI. I'm not sure i'm explaining this the right way.

Comment: for example, if i download a file and check the download url (i was hoping i could trace the actual url!) it displays something like this as the download url: http://ip:port/cgi-bin/filemanager/utilRequest.cgi/2A4334%20BAT%20NATURAL%20(1).JPG and it returns json simply sain: { "status": 3, "success": "true" }

Comment: output:array(20) { [0]=> string(22) "/Network Recycle Bin 1" [1]=> string(7) "/Public" [2]=> string(10) "/Qdownload" [3]=> string(12) "/Qmultimedia" [4]=> string(12) "/Qrecordings" [5]=> string(5) "/Qusb" [6]=> string(5) "/Qweb" [7]=> string(6) "/Users" [8]=> string(9) "/partilha" [9]=> string(9) "/abcndrade" [10]=> string(11) ...

Comment: So that gives you twenty different directories in your home path.  Do you know which folder you're trying to single out?  Perhaps could you be a little more specific on the more broad goal here?  Why are you trying to display images from an FTP server?

Comment: i know which folder i want to take the image from. I can print every content of the folder in the browser. I am developing a web application and i need to load images from a nas.

Comment: Are you the only one using this?  

The only solution I can think of then, is to just put the img tag as `<img src="ftp://user:pass@domain.com:port" />`

This isn't safe at all obviously.  Traditionally, when images are uploaded to a file server, there is also an HTTPD running in tandem with the FTPD, where you can call the images through http, instead of FTP.  

If your apache server is not on the same server as your NAS, this will be difficult.  Hopefully someone else has a clearer answer.  Otherwise I'd recommend looking at hosting them together.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you UPLOADING files to the FTP via web FTP for your web host, and then just want to show them in a webpage, but aren't sure the URL to use for these images?  Or do you already know how to do this?

Comment: yes. i talked to a friend 10 minutes ago and he also gave me the same solution as you, <img src="ftp://user:pass@domain.com:port" />. I told him i would create a user, with the permission to access only the desired folder and with read-only previleges. He also told me, as you did, that it is not safe but i think with a custom-created user just for that purpose wud solve the issue, as i cant think of a better way of doing it nor do i know how to call it from http. your answer is good i'll accept it. Thank you

Comment: can you please update your answer with the last suggestion from the post? It is a solution for me. Thank you for your time and patience. Best regards

Comment: In addition, make sure you only allow that user read privilege.